# How to monitor for async/await deadlocks in MVC4?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, monitoring, async-await

After reading [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)
i decided to test the deadlock behavior in MVC4. After creating the website from  the Intranet template I modified the Index action like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AsyncAwait.MVC4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static async Task DelayAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        // This method causes a deadlock when called in a GUI or ASP.NET context.
        public static void Test()
        {
            // Start the delay.
            var delayTask = DelayAsync();
            // Wait for the delay to complete.
            delayTask.Wait();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            Test();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The call to Index hangs as I expected but I also expected an exception to be thrown at some point. Exception is never thrown however and all requests just hang.

I looked at all available performance counters and could not figure out how to identify a deadlock. If I were to work with an existing website which uses async/await, how can I setup monitoring for potential deadlocks?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect a deadlock to throw an exception?

Comment: @svick: You are correct, I should not be expecting an exception, misread the article I referenced. Still I would like to know if it's possible to monitor deadlocks somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Great question. I think this relates more to multithreading and not directly to the async/await facility. I think your only option is to architect some form of monitoring. I am not aware of an automatic behavior from withing C# or the runtime.

Comment: I don't think the above would hang even.

Comment: @PeteGO It really would. This is because `await` attempts to resume on the context that's blocked by `Wait()`.

Comment: I think in this specific case, the solution is not trying to detect deadlocks, it's to avoid them completely by not using `Wait()`.

Comment: @svick I agree that combination of async and Task.Wait is a problem and per article async should be used all the way through. However my concern is monitoring of an existing code base for these scenarios. One option is of course fixing the code and eliminating Wait altogether. If that is the only option I have I would like to mark your comment as an answer!

Comment: @AlexS: Svick's is the best solution. There is (currently) not sufficient tracing at runtime to detect deadlocks immediately; fortunately, deadlocks like this happen reliably, so it's quite obvious there's a deadlock as soon as you do system-level testing. The tracing situation may improve over the next few years as debugging and visualization tooling works better with `async`. Keep an eye on ETW in particular; there's already some (undocumented) events from the [TPL provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517329.aspx).

Comment: @StephenCleary Thank you, this looks promising. I appreciate your feedback and confirming Svick's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your tasks to complete within predictable time frames then you could use timeouts.

`Task.Wait` has a couple of overloads that take a timeout value.

If for example your task should never take more than 5 seconds you can do something like this.

```
var delayTask = DelayAsync();

// Will be true if DelayAsync() completes within 5 seconds, otherwise false.
bool callCompleted = delayTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

if (!callCompleted)
{
    throw new TimeoutException("Task not completed within expected time.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is definitely one of the approaches to take. I would like to see however if it's possible to observe deadlocks in existing application before fixing any code.